# Filter Specific XML Node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to filter **<end_date/>** element from my XML input using XSLT. I have tried different approaches but does not seem to work. Can you suggest me how it can be achieved

Sample Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <version_id>2005P0</version_id>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484284</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>864</employment_id>
                <end_date/>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484285</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>865</employment_id>
                <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484286</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>866</employment_id>
                <end_date>2021-02-01</end_date>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

Expected output (element to be removed for person_id_external 484284):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <version_id>2005P0</version_id>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484284</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>864</employment_id><end_date/>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484285</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>865</employment_id>
                <end_date>2020-12-31</end_date>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
        <person>
            <person_id_external>484286</person_id_external>
            <employment_information>
                <employment_id>866</employment_id>
                <end_date>2021-02-01</end_date>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

XSL I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="//CompoundEmployee/person/employment_information/end_date[not(end_date)]"/>
 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove any empty `end_date` element? Or that for a particular `person`? And show us one attempt and how it failed exactly.

Comment: Hi Martin, I want to remove any empty end_date element wherever it occurs in payload.

Comment: "*I have tried different approaches but does not seem to work.*" For example?

Comment: I added an XSL which doesnt seem to work in my question. but that is my idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template to remove any empty `end_date` would be simply an empty `<xsl:template match="end_date[not(node())]"/>`.

Comment: Tried like this with your suggestion and it worked.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
   <!-- remove all empty endDate in emp_info elements -->
 <xsl:template match="//CompoundEmployee/person/employment_information/end_date[not(node())]"/>
 
 
 
 </xsl:stylesheet>